# Close mobile menu after link click

Tags: php, mobile, menu

I have a mobile menu that does not close after clicking a menu link because the menu links are anchor points on the same page.

I'm trying to make it so clicking a mobile menu link activates the "close menu" button.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
if( window.outerWidth <= 1024 ) {
    document.querySelector( 'a.hfe-menu-item' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
        document.querySelector( '.elementor-clickable.hfe-flyout-close' ).click();
    });
}
```

`a.hfe-menu-item` is the CSS class of the menu links and `.elementor-clickable.hfe-flyout-close` is the CSS class of the "close menu" button.

But when I try using this code snippet, I get an error saying:

> The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on
> line 2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

What does it mean? What's wrong with line 2? Is the code snippet at least somewhat correct?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've been looking at similar question on Stack Overflow but I couldn't figure it out..

Comment: I see nothing syntactically wrong with this piece of code. Can you please provide additional context? Where are you saving this snippet?

Comment: Hi @El_Vanja, I'm using a WordPress plugin, called "Code Snippets", which adds the code snippets to the functions.php file. [Here's a screenshot of the error.](https://ibb.co/Fn06CTX)

Comment: The error sounds like a PHP error message, so what this means is probably simply that you just tried to put JS code directly into PHP code …

Comment: That is a plugin to insert and execute PHP code. This is probably not what you should be using to insert JavaScript in the first place …